# is it possible to do ?somevalue

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php get variables as key with no value assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680914/php-get-variables-as-key-with-no-value-assigned)

When im working on some of my PHP scripts, I often find it hard to figure our a _GET value that still can make the page look good, so im wondering if it somehow is possible just to do for example index.php?somevalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you can access that value via [`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).