# GET parameter becomes the page name after rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an url that looks like:

```
/platforms.php?platform_id=xxx
```

where `xxx` is a number

I'm rewriting the URL inside the php application. So, for example the above url would look like:

```
/xbox/ or /playstation/
```

Now in .htaccess I have:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ platforms.php?platform_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However when I go to a platform page the GET url becomes `/xbox/ or /playstation/` , instead of `xxx`.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

**Update:**

Hi, the link is not relevant to my question. I've tried to reformulate what I am after for in the example bellow with better details.

Thanks for the answer and sorry for the bad explanation.

Yep, when I said GET url I was referring to $_GET["platform_id"] .

Basically I have an URL called

www.example.com/platforms.php?platform_id=1

In the above example $_GET['platform_id'] = 1.

In the actual php aplication I have a function (let's call it make_link ), with which I make the above URL output like:

www.example.com/xbox/ (since 1 is the id of the xbox platform)

Now in httaccess I also need a rewrite rule that will make accessing the URL work.

So I have :

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ platforms.php?platform_id=$1 [L,QSA]

This does make the rewrite work in the terms that I can access

www.example.com/xbox/

However on the newly accessed page, if I get $_GET['platform_id'], the value for it is xbox/ .

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [$\_GET and URL Rewriting for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505338/get-and-url-rewriting-for-php)

Comment: Can you elaborate "I'm rewriting the URL inside the php application." Are you redirecting through PHP? If yes, are you appending the `id` as well like `/xbox/?platform_id=1` ?

Answer (score 0):

In a RewriteRule, `$1` is a variable backreferencing the first regular expression (in your case: `([^/]+)`).

So, whatever text forms that part of your URL is what will be stored in `$1`.

If you wanted to use the consoles' IDs, you'd have to make these IDs part of your URLs. If you don't want that, but if you want your pretty URLs to reflect the names of the consoles, you'll have to rewrite the query part of `platforms.php?platform_id=$1` in your .htaccess file.

Instead of querying for IDs (`?platform_id=$1`), you'll have to query for the consoles' names, e.g. `?platform_name=$1`.

**Edit:**
In your PHP file, you'd then use `$_GET['platform_name']`

Comment: Lucian, was this what you were looking for?