# I cannot use $_Get when I add my .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website that works fantastic. I'd like to organize it a little better so instead of loading every file by typing it in the url, i'll just make a index file that can include the files by a get method.

```
$key = $_GET['KEY'];
if ($key == 'signup'){
include "forming/signup.php";
}
```

To make the url a little cleaner I added this in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?KEY=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?KEY=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Which turned

> localhost:8888/index?KEY=signup

into

> localhost:8888/signup

Now the only problem is that when I use the $_GET, it simply doesn't notice it. I noticed it by a redirect (Programmed in If statement) so I tested it by making a file and with this code

```
<?php
$test = $_GET['id];
echo "<h1>" . $test . "</h1>";
```

And it didn't work, like expected.

I don't know why $_GET stopped working after I used that .htaccess code.
*(I'm a novice at .htaccess)*

I would truly appreciate if anyone could tell me another way to cleanse the url and still have the $_GET working. (*Or just if you see any error in the .htaccess*)

**UPDATE**

I'd like to clarify. Essentially I want this

> localhost:8888/index.php?KEY=post&id=1

to

> localhost:8888/post/1

(But for every post, not just nr 1)

Comment: That's how the `$_GET` works. It takes the URL and looks for the syntax `key=value` right after `?`. Since you changed the URL structure it is no longer a part of your `$_GET` parameter.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio It's a rewrite though so the server request should still have the GET (if it wasn't being double re-written).

Comment: @uom-pgregorio Is there a way to only rewrite to first key and value?

Comment: My apologies. I don't normally do rewrites so I wasn't aware. Apparently it should "generally" work as expected. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505338/get-and-url-rewriting-for-php

Comment: I tried to use localhost:8888/index.php?KEY=about&id=1 and it worked,
it doesn't work if I use it trough the rewritten url:
localhost:8888/about?id=1

Comment: @user3783243 I'm so sorry. I tried to remove the ones beneath the line you showed, removed on of the lines with almost the same string + changed the / to an ? but it didn't solve my main problem

Comment: @user3783243 That line made so the $_GET worked but also made so that the other rewrite(KEY) work

Comment: @user3783243
None. They just de-effected each other. If I typed the:
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L,QSA] before the RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?KEY=$1 it just wouldn't let the beneath one work.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?KEY=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?KEY=$1` can just be `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?KEY=$1` that is the same. I'm not sure about your current issue though. I would do some logging on the rewrite rules to see what is matching. It sounds like you aren't passing the query string on the second request though. (You also are correct, it is possible to use `GET` without having it in the URL bar, that is how rewrites work)

Comment: Here's a clear example:
I want this etc; localhost:8888/index.php?KEY=about&id=1 to
localhost:8888/about?id=1

Comment: That's backwards, right? You load `localhost:8888/about?id=1` and it should request `localhost:8888/index.php?KEY=about&id=1` right?

Comment: @user3783243 Exactly!

Comment: Maybe https://pastebin.com/SNujWbRT? Actually add the `[NC,L]` at the end of the `rewriterule` line

Answer (score 0):

As PHP is a server-side language, `$_GET` only works on what's actually in the URL string at the time the request is sent to the server. If you purely want to alter what's visible in the address bar in order to achieve a cleaner look, you'll need to use a server-side language.

Luckily you can do this with Javascript `pushState`. [There's an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22753103/revisions) that covers it in all possible detail.

Comment: This is incorrect. You should research `rewrite` rules.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you have to involve Js in this. I'd just like to know how to rewrite the url so it doesn't affect the following keys and values (Except for the first one that actually points to what page)

Answer (score 0):

If you want my advice, follow these steps to get the best site :)

1 -> First, create folder in your public_html , name it : "auth" for example

in this folder you can upload you files like "signin.php" , "signup.php" , "forget_password.php"

2 -> in your htaccess file , put this :

I've written this file for you, he is ready :)

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            deny from 10.0.0.182
            AddDefaultCharset utf-8
            Options -MultiViews
            Options -Indexes
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
            RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
            RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
            #REDIRECTS HERE LIKE REF SYSTEM
            RewriteRule ^ref/(.*)$ auth/signup?ref=$1 [L]
       </IfModule>  
   </IfModule>
```

3 -> Your links now is :

- http://example.com/auth/signin
- http://example.com/auth/signup
- http://example.com/auth/forget_password
- http://example.com/ref/username

**NOTE : in ref system , you can get username value from $_GET['ref']**

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate this.Since that was coded and understood by you I'd like to ask if there a way for me to do this with less .htaccess code because the folder "auth" wasn't the real problem. My main will is to rewrite the index?KEY=signup or any key to just /key